# Angular 2 upgrade to rc5

Tags: angular

I want to use forms provided in rc5, but I find it difficult to update to that version.  I tried to follow this tutorial http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/22/model-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html but it didn't work with rc3

Here is my boot.ts

```
import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import {FORM_PROVIDERS, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/http';
import { AUTH_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { AuthGuard } from './common/auth.guard';
import {routes} from "./app.routes";
import {provide} from "@angular/core";

bootstrap(
AppComponent,
[
    provideRouter(routes),

    FORM_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    AUTH_PROVIDERS,
    AuthGuard,
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
]
);
```

I know that I should you @NgModule, but I don't exactly how to rewrite this.

How can I rewrite this ?

Comment: Just open this plunker and start from there.
https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/forms/ts/plnkr.html The documentation is here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `main.ts` should look like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Your then need to create `app.module.ts` which should look like this, I can't be 100% certain on all things though:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthGuard } from './common/auth.guard';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
        routing,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
    ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

I'm not sure about `AUTH_PROVIDES`, you can check how to use `angular2-jwt` in RC5+ [here](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/137).

For more information about migrating to RC5+, check official [RC4 to RC5 Migration doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html), as well as [Angular Modules doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) to understand RC5 changes. You can also read [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) on official Angular 2 GitHub repository.